How to manage third-party dependencies within my local AAR
I have a custom Android library that requires a publicly available third-party dependency, com.opencsv:opencsv. I would like to manage this dependency myself, without requiring my clients to implement it in their projects.
Prior to Android Gradle plugin 7.9, I could use fat-aar to embed third-party dependencies within my AAR, but this approach might increase the library size. Unfortunately, fat-aar is no longer available for AGP 8.0 or later.
My question is, how can I manage third-party dependencies within my local AAR? Is it possible to have Gradle automatically install the required dependencies when my clients implement my AAR in their app's build.gradle?
Here is my current setup:
My library's build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation "com.opencsv:opencsv:3.10"
}

My client app's build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/my-custom-library.aar')
    
    implementation "com.opencsv:opencsv:3.10" // <---- I don't want this line
}


You need to have the opencsv library as a remote dependency inside your aar. Or you could add opencsv as a jar file to your aar.
